# Correct way to calculate the S&P500 average CAGR of earnings over 10 years rolling periods

Tags: earnings, sp500, rolling, cagr

Let's say we have only the following data for the earnings (*e*) and we calculated for each 10 years period the total earnings growth (*G*) and its Compounded Annual Growth Rate (*AG*)

\begin{equation}
\\G_n = {e_n/e_{n-1}}-1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\\AG_n = \sqrt[10]{1+G_n}-1
\end{equation}

[image]

What's the correct way to calculate the average CAGR of the earnings over these 10 years periods?

Method 1) We could do the average of *G* and than calculate the CAGR of such average
\begin{equation}
\\CAGR1 = \sqrt[10]{1+\frac{\sum{G_n}}{n}}-1
\end{equation}

Method 2) We could simply do the average of the *AG*
\begin{equation}
\\CAGR2 = \frac{\sum{AG_n}}{n}
\end{equation}

In this simple example there is a little difference in the result (1.86% vs 1.79%), **but still there is a difference in the result**.

I can understand the results are different because they are algebraically different, but **I can't intuitively understand how they can be different. Which is the one that really represents the correct average?**

---

I tried to calculate the same thing using [S&P500 earnings](http://www.econ.yale.edu/~shiller/data/ie_data.xls) over rolling 10 years periods (since March/1957 to September/2019) and the result are very different:

If I use method (1) I get an average total earning growth over 10 years of 107,59% and its CAGR is 7.6%

If I use method (2) I get an average CAGR of 6.4%

Which one is the correct method?

If they are both correct and I have being asked by someone - ***"What has been the  historical average annual compounded growth rate of the earnings of the S&P500 over 10 years?"*** - what should I answer - **7.6% or 6.4%?**

Comment: it occurs to me a better question is why you need an average of rolling 10y CAGR?  there's not really a need to calculate an average given the question you asked above...the compound annual growth rate (which is itself an 'average' annual return) can be calculated directly

Comment: @Chris each 10 year period has a different CAGR of the earnings, I want to know what was the average CAGR.

Comment: I realize that, but it isn't clear why you'd need that.  At a minimum, in taking an average over your rolling CAGR, you're double counting annual returns.  That's a weird thing to do.

Comment: @Chris I need it to answer the question *"What has been the historical average annual compounded growth rate of the earnings of the S&P500 over 10 years periods?"*